# Excel(Google Sheets) ArrayFormula + If statment with one output?

Tags: google-sheets-query

I have the following formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA((IF(B16>C16:F16, "Some Text", "")))`

What I am trying to achieve is:

If B16 is greater than each of C16:F16 then the cell text should be "Some Text".

Currently the formula will poulate a cell with "Some Text" for each C16:F16 rather than just once. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Google's Visualization API Query Language, but perhaps achieves the result you wanted:

```
=if(B16>min(C16:F16),"some text","")
```